# Why the fulltext search failed on Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

Tested on [datomic-free](https://clojars.org/com.datomic/datomic-free) 0.9.5697, clojure 1.10.3 and openjdk 17.01.

```clj
(require '[datomic.api :as d])

(def uri "datomic:mem://test")
(d/create-database uri)
(def conn (d/connect uri))
(def db (-> conn d/db delay))

(def schema [{:db/ident :person/name
              :db/valueType :db.type/string
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}])
(d/transact conn schema)

(def datoms [{:person/name "Oliver Smith"}])
(d/transact conn datoms)

(def query '[:find ?name
             :where
             [_ :person/name ?name]])
(-> (d/q query @db) println) ; ok => #{[Oliver Smith]}

(def query '[:find ?name
             :where
             [(fulltext $ :person/name "Smith") [[_ ?name]]]])

(-> (d/q query @db) println) ; nok => expected: #{[Oliver Smith]}, actual: #{}
```

Why did the above [fulltext](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html#fulltext) search return empty?

Comment: I think the schema definition is missing `:db/fulltext true` to enable [fulltext indexing](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/schema/schema.html#operational-schema-attributes) on the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Steffan Westcott has pointed out, we need add `:db/fulltext true` to the desired attribute in the schema thus enable the feature of fulltext search on it. Now it works after wasting hours to find out myself. Thanks a ton, Steffan.

According to the [doc](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/schema/schema.html#operational-schema-attributes),

> :db/fulltext specifies a boolean value indicating that an eventually
> consistent fulltext search index should be generated for the
> attribute. Defaults to false.

So the said schema is corrected below,

```clj
(def schema [{:db/ident :person/name
              :db/valueType :db.type/string
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
              :db/fulltext true}
            ])
```

We can demonstrate that fulltext search on Datomic works by another example below - find who are "Smith" and "music" is one of their hobbies.

test.clj

```clj
(require '[datomic.api :as d])

(def uri "datomic:mem://test")
(d/create-database uri)
(def conn (d/connect uri))
(def db (-> conn d/db delay))

(def schema [{:db/ident :person/name
              :db/valueType :db.type/string
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
              :db/fulltext true}
             {:db/ident :person/hobby
              :db/valueType :db.type/string
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
              :db/fulltext true}
             ])
(d/transact conn schema)

(def datoms [{:person/name "Oliver Smith" :person/hobby "reading, sports and music"}
             {:person/name "Amelia Smith" :person/hobby "reading, music and dance"}
             {:person/name "George Smith" :person/hobby "reading and sports"}
             {:person/name "Amelia Jones" :person/hobby "reading, music and dance"}
             ])
(d/transact conn datoms)

(def query '[:find ?name ?hobby
             :where
             [(fulltext $ :person/name "Smith") [[?p ?name]]]
             [(fulltext $ :person/hobby "music") [[?p ?hobby]]]
             ])
(-> (d/q query @db) println) ; ok
```

run it to get the expected result below,

```
$ clj -Sdeps '{:deps {com.datomic/datomic-free {:mvn/version "0.9.5697"}}}' -M test.clj

stdout: #{[Oliver Smith reading, sports and music]
          [Amelia Smith reading, music and dance]}
```